# Set Limit for TextField characters in RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I want to set a limit for characters in a textFiled using RxSwift, 
may be i can benefit from `Scan` operator but i don't know how to use it in this case ,

I want my resulting code to behave as same as implementing it in `shouldChangeCharacterInRage` method:

```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String)
        -> Bool {
            if textField == baseTextFiled{
                let enteredString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
                if enteredString.count > limit{ // limit defined previously
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

ReactiveX pushes data, so isn't really compatible with that particular delegate method. That said, you can still do it because `.rx.text` is a control property...

```
baseTextField.rx.text.orEmpty          // pushes text
    .map { String($0.prefix(limit)) }  // pushes first X characters in text
    .distinctUntilChanged()            // only pushes if text is different than previously
    .bind(to: baseTextField.rx.text)   // pushes text into text field
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: thx Daniel for the help however your solution work only if i remove `distinctUntilChanged() `